# Combine all plots into one graph

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions

How can I combine all these plots into one one graph?

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := (a*x^2 + b*x + c)/3;
tup1 := RandomInteger[5, {15, 3}];
Plot[f[##], {x, 0, 10}] & @@@ tup1
```

Comment: `Plot[f @@@ tup1 // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the plots are already created, you can combine them using `Show` and post-process to change line colors:

```
tup = tup1;
plots = Plot[f[##], {x, 0, 10}] & @@@ tup;

Show[plots]
```

[image]

```
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ tup];

Legended[Show[plots, ImageSize -> Large] /. _?ColorQ :> 
   Last[colors = RotateLeft[colors]], 
  LineLegend[colors, tup]]
```

[image]